# Prefix is not working in gatsby-plugin-advanced-sitemap

Tags: gatsby, netlify, ghost-blog

I have a Gatsby site that uses the plugin '**gatsby-plugin-advanced-sitemap**' and it is hosted in Netlify. I have added prefix as /blog. But its not displaying when the sitemap is generated. Can someone please help regarding this?

```
 mapping: {
   allGhostPost: {
      sitemap: `posts`,
      prefix: 'blog/',
   },
   allGhostPage: {
      sitemap: `pages`,
   },
 },
```